# "host" command returning NXDOMAIN on a domain with nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, host

I'm trying to check a domain's availability using the "host" command and looking for NXDOMAIN response. I've come across an odd domain though:

```
host -W 1 antiquejewelry.net
```

This returns NXDOMAIN, yet [the whois record](http://who.is/whois/antiquejewelry.net/) shows its nameservers set to:

```
nsf.algx.net
rapnet.diamonds.com
```

Is there any particular reason for this response? Is there a better way to check for the existence of a domain's nameservers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My WHOIS results show these two name servers:

```
RAPNET.DIAMONDS.COM
NS.DIGEX.NET
```

The name servers 'exist' in the WHOIS results but no listed name server responds with records for this domain.  Check the output of both `host` and `dig` using the two servers listed in the WHOIS as well as the other on you have listed in your question:

Using `host`:

```
dave@dev:/var$ host antiquejewelry.net rapnet.diamonds.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

dave@dev:/var$ host antiquejewelry.net ns.digex.net
host: couldn't get address for 'ns.digex.net': not found

dave@dev:/var$ host antiquejewelry.net nsf.algx.net
Using domain server:
Name: nsf.algx.net
Address: 207.88.20.150#53
Aliases:

Host antiquejewelry.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Using `dig`:

```
dave@dev:/var$ dig @rapnet.diamonds.com antiquejewelry.net

; <<>> DiG 9.5.1-P2 <<>> @rapnet.diamonds.com antiquejewelry.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

dave@dev:/var$ dig @ns.digex.net antiquejewelry.net
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns.digex.net': not found

dave@dev:/var$ dig @nsf.algx.net antiquejewelry.net

; <<>> DiG 9.5.1-P2 <<>> @nsf.algx.net antiquejewelry.net
; (3 servers found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8959
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;antiquejewelry.net.            IN      A

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: 207.88.20.150#53(207.88.20.150)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 25 10:19:16 2009
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36
```

The connection times-out to the first name server, the second name server's host name doesn't resolve, and the third name server responds indicating that it doesn't have a zone for antiquejewelry.net (it has no records for that domain).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Dave. Do you have any suggestions for determining whether or not a domain is available aside from WHOIS?

Comment: If you're looking to check for domain availability, WHOIS is your best bet (though not perfect because there can be some delay).

Answer (score 2):

It is a funny case of **lame delegation**. Lame delegation is when a domain is delegated to name servers which are not aware of it (by misconfiguration or any other reason). Typically, a server which does not have the delegation replies SERVFAIL (Server Failure) or NOERROR with a redirect to the root but `nsf.algx.NET` replies NXDOMAIN (No Such Domain) with the AA (Authoritative Answer) flag, something it clearly has non business to do.

So, here, you've found an interesting example of brokenness.

Otherwise, checking a domain availability by using the DNS is a very bad idea because, in many registries, a domain can be registered and not published, at the will of the domain owner.